# Getting the Right Metric from Google Analytics [Node.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics, google-api

I'm trying to retrieve the 8.15% metric in this screenshot (Registration (Goal 1 Conversion Rate)) in my Node.js app.

[image]

The problem is that the output of my code is 4.40% -- this is the 'avg for view' metric right under the 8.15% metric on the page. Here's my code attempt so far.

```
var google = require('googleapis');

//authentication code [hidden, this works already]

// Get percentage of new registrations
exports.registrations = function(callback) {
  analytics.data.ga.get({
    auth: jwtClient,
    ids: config.ga.viewId,
    metrics: 'ga:goal1ConversionRate',
    dimensions: 'ga:pagePath',
    'start-date': '2016-04-01',
    'end-date': 'yesterday',
  }, function(err, data) {
    if (err) return callback(err);
    callback(null, {
      registrations: Number(data.totalsForAllResults['ga:goal1ConversionRate']),
    });
  });
};
```

I have my app setup so that when i visit /ga/registrations, I see the JSON response of the above code snippet, which is 4.40%.

I know that its just a parameter switch somewhere but I'm not sure what I should change.

I'm trying to ask Google Analytics this question---

Give me the Goal 1 Conversion rate metric for all the pages that contain /docs in the URL.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a filter somewhere, I'm not familiar with node.js but based on the syntax and other ways of accessing the API that I am familiar with you'll need to add something like

```
filters:'ga:landingPagePath=@/docs'
```